# Can there be a solution to Sin(prime(n))==Sin(prime(m))

Tags: analysis

Awhile ago I was messing around with Return Maps, and decided to input the prime numbers into a return map. I have uploaded a picture of what I created. As you can see there are elliptical structures generated. How am I able to interpolate elliptical functions from these points on the return map? Plus I came to the realization could there be a set(s) of primes that can satisfy the conjecture of Sin(prime(n))==Sin(prime(m))?[image: Return map of Sin(Prime)]

Comment: What does $\operatorname{prime}(n)$ refer to? Does it generate all prime numbers $\le n$? Does it check if $n$ is a prime number? What exactly?

Comment: Nice, this are Lissajou figures, or nearby. How did you obtain this plot, a list of numbers between -1 and 1 has only one dimension... Maybe you mean (sin(p);sin(next p))? In this case the result is less strange.

Comment: If two *integers* $a$ and $b$ satisfy $\sin a=\sin b$, then we must have $a = b$.

Comment: prime(n) is the notation I went with for the nth prime number. right now I don't have access to any math editing software so it is difficult for me to place my equations in notation. Since I created a return map then each point represents (sin(p),sin(p+1)).

Comment: As for the a=b conjecture then it won't be possible. However, looking at all points near each other might hold some sort of meaning.

Comment: Here is my coding using SageMath 8.6:
a = 1000000;
p = [i for i in prime_range(a)] *All primes from zero to one million*;
sp = [sin(p[i]) for i in range(len(p))] *List of all sin(p) from zero to one million*;
sprm = [(sp[i],sp[i+1]) for i in range(len(sp)-1)] *Return map list of sin(p) from 0 to one million*;
list_plot(sprm, size = 1, dpi = 640, fontsize = 5) *Plotting return map*